# SQL subqueries with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, group-by

I am trying to summarize invoice line-items using subqueries. Each invoice has multiple rows in `TRANS` table, some of which are item amounts and some of which are `$tax` amounts. Оne invoice can have multiple items and multiple taxes.

I want to add up all the tax items into one total and all the widget amounts into one total and group it all by invoice number. I can write a query that groups the tax by invoice and one that groups the items by invoice but I can't figure out how to group it all. Here are the two seperate statements:

```
    SELECT TRANSNUM AS Invoice_Num, SUM(DAMOUNT) AS Total_Tax from DETAIL d
    JOIN TRANS t on t.ID = d.ID
    where d.POSTDATE= '2018-01-01' and t.type=6 and d.ACCT =52
    GROUP BY TRANSNUM 
    ORDER BY TRANSNUM

    SELECT TRANSNUM AS Invoice_Num, SUM(DAMOUNT) AS Total_of_Items from DETAIL d
    JOIN TRANS t on t.ID = d.ID
    where d.POSTDATE= '2018-01-01' and t.type=6 and d.ACCT !=52
    GROUP BY TRANSNUM  
    ORDER BY TRANSNUM
```

As you can see, the statements are virtually the same, except one sums **ACCT=52** (the tax account) and the other sums **ACCT<>52** (all the other accounts).

In the end, I'm trying to create a result set with column headings: **Invoice_Num, Total_of_Items, Total_Tax and Tax_Percent** (Tax_Percent is just a calculated column of Total_Tax/Total_of_Items).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation, and compute both the total tax and total of items in a single pass over the table, using `CASE` expressions:

```
SELECT
    TRANSNUM AS Invoice_Num,
    SUM(CASE WHEN d.ACCT = 52  THEN DAMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS Total_Tax,
    SUM(CASE WHEN d.ACCT <> 52 THEN DAMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS Total_of_Items
FROM DETAIL d
INNER JOIN TRANS t
    ON t.ID = d.ID
WHERE
    d.POSTDATE= '2018-01-01' AND t.type=6
GROUP BY
    TRANSNUM 
ORDER BY
    TRANSNUM;
```

You will notice that most of the logic in the `WHERE` clause remains as is.  This is because the two queries both shared this logic.

Comment: Thanks - is there a way to compute the Tax_Percent without repeating both SUM statements? i.e. better than: CAST((SUM(CASE WHEN d.ACCT = 52  THEN DAMOUNT ELSE 0 END)/SUM(CASE WHEN d.ACCT <>52 THEN DAMOUNT ELSE 0 END)*100) AS DECIMAL(10,1)) AS Tax_Percent

Comment: @Andrew You're pretty much limited to repeating the `CASE` expressions.  Or, you could subquery what I wrote above and take the quotient there.  But that would result in bad performance.

Answer (score 0):

In other way you could also use `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT Invoice_Num, SUM(Total_Tax) Total_Tax, SUM(Total_of_Items) Total_of_Items  
FROM 
(
    SELECT TRANSNUM AS Invoice_Num, SUM(DAMOUNT) AS Total_Tax, 0 AS Total_of_Items  
    from DETAIL d
    JOIN TRANS t on t.ID = d.ID
    where d.POSTDATE= '2018-01-01' and t.type=6 and d.ACCT =52
    GROUP BY TRANSNUM 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TRANSNUM AS Invoice_Num, 0 AS Total_Tax,  SUM(DAMOUNT) AS Total_of_Items 
    from DETAIL d
    JOIN TRANS t on t.ID = d.ID
    where d.POSTDATE= '2018-01-01' and t.type=6 and d.ACCT !=52
    GROUP BY TRANSNUM 
) t
GROUP BY Invoice_Num
```

However, conditional aggregation is more effective way but still `union all` also useful.

Answer (score 0):

First find Total_of_Items and Total_Tax with inner query then finaly get Tax_Percent  from Total_Tax and Total_of_Items ad per below:

```
select A.Invoice_Num, A.Total_of_Items, A.Total_Tax,  (A.Total_Tax / A.Total_of_Items) as Tax_Percent 
from (  
SELECT TRANSNUM AS Invoice_Num, 
SUM( case when d.ACCT = 52 then 0 else DAMOUNT end) AS Total_of_Items,
SUM( case when d.ACCT =52 then DAMOUNT else 0 end) AS Total_Tax
from DETAIL d
JOIN TRANS t on t.ID = d.ID
where d.POSTDATE= '2018-01-01' and t.type=6 
GROUP BY TRANSNUM  
) as A
ORDER BY A.Invoice_Num
```

Comment: Thanks, this way worked nicely also - executed a bit slower because of the inner/outer query construction though. I think last line needs to be ORDER BY A.Invoice_Num  Cheers.